# powershell copy files on remote

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to copy files to a remote server

```
Copy-Item $localDir \\serverA\deploy -recurse
```

After, I want to make a local copy on the remote server

```
Copy-Item \\serverA\deploy \\serverA\production
```

How can I execute this last command on the server, in order to speed up copy time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-Command` and `Get-Credential` to perform a command on the remote computer.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "ServerA" -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {Copy-Item C:\deploy C:\production} -Authentication Kerberos
```

If you want to keep the session open for longer so that use can use it more that once, you can use `New-PSSession`.

```
# Setup Session with Credentials 
$Creds= Get-Credential -UserName "Domain\Username" -Message "Enter Password"
$psSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "ServerA" -Credential $Creds -Authentication Kerberos 

# Run a command
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock {Copy-Item \\serverA\deploy \\serverA\production}
...
# Run another command later
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock {<#Another command later on...#>}
```

Use the following to pass in parameters to the session.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ArgumentList @($serverPath1,$serverPath2) -ScriptBlock {
    Param($serverPath1,$serverPath2)
    Copy-Item $serverPath1 $serverPath2
}
```

Make sure you close the connection after use with the following

```
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

**Note:** You will need to make your `WinRM` is configured and running on the server for remote management. You can run a quick config with the command (`winrm qc`).

Comment: What if server paths are in variables?