# Powershell v5.1 : Copy from share server to local folder on a remote PC

Tags: powershell, windows-10, credentials, powershell-5.0

I have to manage around 10 PC running window 10. 
I need to copy some software to those PC from share folder ( \company\folder or \MyPC\SharedFolder)
Manual remote is okay, however, doing copy item from share folder to 10 PC is take time and boring.
I found use `Invoke-command` and `copy-item` can help me to do it faster. However, I get error `Access is denied`

```
$usr = "UserName"
$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String Password
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "$usr",$pw

For ($i=1; $i -lt 11; $i++)
{
    $computerName=""
    if($i -lt 10) {
        $computerName="PC000$i"
    } else {
        $computerName="PC00$i"
    }
    Write-host "Copy on $computerName"
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "ServerA" -Credential $creds -Authentication Kerberos
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item \\CompanyFolder\Shared\Sample.zip D:\Shared }
}
```

And below is error

```
Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\CompanyFolder\Shared\Sample.zip:String) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : PC0007

Cannot find path '\\CompanyFolder\Shared\Sample.zip' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\CompanyFolder\Shared\Sample.zip:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : PC0007
```

I search around and find similar issues at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102390/powershell-copy-files-on-remote) but it can not fix my issue. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does the user you are logging in have accessrights on the share? Btw. you are creating PSSessoins but are not removing them. Use `Remove-PSSession` to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks for the note. The user have full permission on network share folder and local folder. If I understand right what you ask

Comment: Try `Enter-PSSession` to use the `$Session` as interactive CLI. That way you can `Test-Path` or use `cd` and `dir` to see if there are any other problems.

Comment: I try with `Enter-PSSession` and `Test-Path`, the result is `Fasle`. I test with `Test-Path` on my PC, and the result is `False` too. I guess the issue related to `Network sharing` via Local Lan. However, I don't know what I need to config for shared folder?

Comment: I update more information, My PC's already update rule, I use the test-path and the result is `True`, however, the result is still `access denied` with error `UnauthorizedAccessException`

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I find the Solution, and it is workaround solutions for this problem.
`Copy-Item -ToSession $session -Path \\CompanyFolder\Shared\Samples.zip -Destination D:\ -Recurse`
More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741609/copy-file-remotely-with-powershell?noredirect=1&lq=1)